# How to get the value of exports.locals of a module after succeed-module event?

Tags: node.js, webpack

This gives me the source code of the subject module:

```
compiler.plugin('compilation', (compilation) => {
  compilation.plugin('succeed-module', (module) => {
    console.log(module._source.source());
  });
});
```

The source code is given as a string. The source code includes  `exports.locals` property:

```
exports = module.exports = require("./../../node_modules/css-loader/lib/css-base.js")();
// imports

// module
exports.push([module.id, ".app-test-fooBarBaz {\n  background: #f00;\n}", ""]);

// exports
exports.locals = {
  "fooBarBaz": "app-test-fooBarBaz"
};

[..]
```

Is there a way to access just the value of `exports.locals` from the `compilation` object?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find where the value of the `exports.locals` is generated. Therefore, the only alternative solution is to extract the value from the string. To do that, I have used [`AST-Query`](https://github.com/SBoudrias/AST-query) to resolve the subject assignment and then [`escodegen`](https://github.com/estools/escodegen) to generate the object, i.e.

```
import program from 'ast-query';
import escodegen from 'escodegen';

const nodes = program(module._source.source()).assignment('exports.locals');
escodegen.generate(nodes.nodes[0]);
```

That does work (it extracts the value of the object in the earlier example). However, if it makes a lot of assumptions about the structure of the input code. Furthermore, it is most likely not the right solution – there must be a way to access `modules.exports` value before it was converted to the string.

I have used this solution to solve a particular problem. Documenting the solution for others reference.

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be done from the compilation instead from the webpack `parser` instance. You can hook into any symbol in the ast of your code. The complete list is found [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/plugins.html#the-parser-instance).

If you are looking to modify the values I believe you can use the webpack-sources library.